# How to fix error in sql "Execution finished with errors. Result: near "(": syntax error"?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How to remove all characters from / to &.

```
UPDATE bal SET Perevod=substr(Perevod, INSTR(Perevod, '/.+&')-1) 
WHERE INSTR(Perevod, '/.+&')>0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this because I believe there is no LEFT function in SQLite:

```
UPDATE bal
SET Perevod = substr(Perevod, 1, INSTR(Perevod, '/')-1)
WHERE INSTR(Perevod, '/')>0;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3ae4e7fcc759b067ea876ead5394f292)